# Attempting to have a div container with bg extend vertically without scrollbars

Tags: css

What I want is to have a centered content column that has a bg with a long vertical gradient. It will most likely extend past the browser, however I don't want it to create scrollbars. I want it to act as if it were like the body background where it continues and is only revealed if the browser is larger or there is more content.

Comment: A `background-image` *will* only be revealed if the content's  height/width warrants it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this. My example used tables, but you can try to replace it with div layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>aruseni</title>
        <style type="text/css">
body {
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: #000;
   background-color: #9b9b9b;
}

html, body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
   border:none
}

a, a:link {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000;
}

a:visited {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #444;
}

img {
   border: 0;
}

table.site {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border-spacing: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 80%;
   height: 100%;
   min-width: 700px;
}

tr {
   vertical-align: top;
}

td {
   padding: 0;
}

td.left_side {
   width: 200px;
}

td.right_side {
   width: 200px;
}

td.content {
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-image:url('gradient-1x2000.png');
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   width: 200px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table class="site">
            <tr style="padding: 0px;">
                <td class="left_side">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="content">
                    <p>Your contents go here. :)</p>
                </td>
                <td class="right_side">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The gradient here is an image with 2000 height and 1 weight. The gradient starts in the top, and if the browser’s height is more than 2000 pixels (oh, really?), as “background-color: #fff;” specifies, the white colour is rendered.